# How to add a list of integers as a column to a spark dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I to convert the list to a dataset and join them but didn't work also tried to use use .union method but it also didn't work as the number of columns in the dataframe are more than the dataframe of one column which is the list of integers in my case

Comment: pls share how does the input and output data looks like for a better user understanding

Comment: are the values in the integer list mapped to some particular value in the Existing data frame ?